# Windows to Raspberry Pi Zero Serial Issues

Tags: python, c++, windows, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm sending data over a serial port using the window's WriteFile function. This is being received by a raspberry pi zero running a python script sitting in a pyserial readline loop (code below). On windows side, I'm putting a file's contents into a buffer and then calling the WriteFile function. It works great for about the first 95-99% of data, as in, the raspberry pi receives that data fine. I'm transmitting a file content's that is about 200 KB in size so it gets a lot of good data, but not the data at the end. Whenever I send a smaller amount of data, like just a line, then most of the line is mangled.

Windows Code (the relevant bits):

```
config.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
config.BaudRate = 115200;
config.Parity = NOPARITY;
config.fBinary = TRUE;
config.fParity = TRUE;
config.ByteSize = 8;

//10 second time out
COMMTIMEOUTS timeOuts;
timeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 10000;
timeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 10000;
timeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10000;
timeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10000;
timeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10000;

char* packet_buffer;

if (!WriteFile(dataFile, packet_buffer, size, &bytesRead, NULL))
{
    _tprintf("There is a problem: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Raspberry Pi Python Script(relevant bits):

```
ser = serial.Serial(
        port = '/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 115200,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout = 10
)

data = open("data.txt", "w")

while 1:
    x = ser.readline()
    data.write(x)
```

Sorry if this question is vague but I've been fiddling with this for a couple days now. My "gut feeling" is that this is something wrong with the raspberry pi zero hardware(like it's just not quick enough or something), but that doesn't exactly make sense when it receives a couple hundred KB just fine.

Comment: Try lowering your baud rate, or enable some sort of flow control. Really, you should be using flow control either way. It's in the [DCB structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes lower the baud rate to e.g. 19200 see if it gets better which would probably indicate flow control is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys but I managed to figure it out.

I finally broke out the logic analyzer and saw that the pi was receiving everything that was being transmitted, it's just not everything in the buffer was being transmitted over the serial cable.

Turns out the serial cable I was/am using is shit. I tried using a different one and it successfully transmitted all the data.

Here is the bad cable (came with the pi zero starter kit or something): https://www.adafruit.com/product/954?gclid=CIaF2_CX_NMCFU02gQodotIDmA

The cable that actually worked: http://www.gearmo.com/shop/usb-to-3-3v-ttl-pin-header-cable-gm-ttl3vt/

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling flow control.

On the python side, set `rtscts=1` in your ctor:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
        port = '/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 115200,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout = 10,
        rtscts = True
)
```

On the win c++ side, enable hardware flow control in the [DCB Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DCB dcb;
SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
fSuccess = GetCommState(dataFile, &dcb)
dcb.fOutX = false;
dcb.fInX = false;
dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = true;
dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = true;
dcb.fDsrSensitivity = true;
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
```